# Does the increasing popularity of index fund investing mean that it will become unprofitable in the future?

Tags: stocks, investing, etf, index-fund

Index fund investing has become increasingly popular over the past 20+ years. More and more people seem to be pouring money into stock index funds in hope that future returns would be as good as they were in the past. If more and more investors do this, wouldn't it become unprofitable in the future? Wouldn't this be a case of "it is going to work well until everyone does it", similar to how countless other trading/investing strategies have been profitable until they became common knowledge and accessible to everyone?

Comment: There was a question in the last few weeks (which of course I can't find now) that touched on this. At some level, if everyone only bought index funds than stocks would not be 'fairly' priced. However, something like 95% or more of trades now are not by index funds, so not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

### Index funds aren't trying to outperform the market; thus they have no edge to lose.

I believe the source of your confusion is that you are confusing the excess returns that active trading strategies seek to achieve with "profitability".  A strategy can fail to beat the market, but if the market is generating a positive return, the strategy will still be profitable.  Passively managed index funds are built on the assumption that that average performance is good enough, and they just seek to minimize fees. Thus, they can never lose their edge because they never had one to begin with.  Their value to investors is that they provide average returns at low cost.

Active trading strategies, on the other hand, seek to use the strategist's knowledge and insight to produce returns that exceed the market average, at least on a risk-adjusted basis.  Often this means exploiting mismatches between the market price of an asset and its "true" value (whatever the strategy thinks that is).  However, trading based on this mispricing tends to push the market price toward the true value, which diminishes the strategy's edge.  That doesn't mean the strategy can't make money, just that it can't make the kind of above average returns that investors who use them are looking for.

Comment: "A strategy can fail to beat the market, but if the market is generating a positive return, the strategy will still be profitable." — How will a strategy that fails to beat the market still be profitable? Isn't there a possibility that the strategy could have negative absolute returns?

Comment: If the market has positive returns, which it often does, then a strategy that fails to beat the market will also have positive returns, so long as it doesn't underperform so badly that it cancels out the market's returns.  For example, if the market returns 7%, then a strategy that returns only 5% has failed to beat the market, but it still made a positive return.

Comment: If I were being more careful, I would have said "might" instead of "will", in the sentence you quoted, since it is possible for a strategy to lag the market so badly that it has negative returns when the market was positive.  When I was writing the answer I had in mind a strategy that failed to beat the market by merely matching it.